# how to hide default ios7 back button image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a piece of code that puts an image inside the navigation bar back button. But then both buttons appear, the one I am putting there and the iOS7 default one. like this:

[image: tabbar]

if there's a way that I can hide the dafault button, or at least make it white, so I can use it.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:stringBackButtonName style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

    newBackButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton"];

    [[sender navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make default button white using tintColor like this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: That's amazing, I've already used this code but it haven't worked. Now it works! Probably it was just a typo. A typo that took me 2 hours... Thanks!